# Restrict download file bandwidth/speed in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, download

we got high-load java application which works in clustered mode.

I need  to add ability to download and upload files for our customers.
For storing files i'm going to user gridFs, not sure, it's best choice, but mongo can be clustered and mongo can replicate data between diff nodes.
That's exactly what i need.

Different group of users should be limited with different bandwidth. Based of some business rules i should restrict download speed for some users.
I saw few [solutions](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/AFilterInputStreamwithalimitedbandwith.htm) for this

Most of them works same way.

- Read bunch of bytes
- Sleep thread
- Repeat

Mongo simply provide me InputStrem and i can read from that stream and write to servlet output stream. I'm not sure it is valid approach. Also I'm afraid, that users can create a lot of concurent threads during download and it can hurt performance.

Could it be an issue for servlet container ?

If it could be an issue, how can it be avoided ? probably using nio ?

I prefer to use pure java solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Leaky bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) or [token bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) algorithms can be used to control the network bandwidth.

EDIT: I did some quick prototyping and implemented the algorithm leveraging Servlet 3.0 asynchronous processing. [Results](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/tenfold-increase-in-server-throughput.html) are pretty good. Full source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/token-bucket). Have fun!

Comment: I created an example application especially for you :-) (see EDIT).

Comment: Nice article, but with regard to single thread per connection issue, this has already been solved with NIO for long. It can go up to 20K concurrent connections on a single thread when you've enough RAM. Tomcat ships with NIO as well, it's only by default disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I'm afraid, that users can create a lot of concurent threads during download and it can hurt performance.
>
> Could it be an issue for servlet container ?

Yes, it could.

> If it could be an issue, how can it be avoided ? probably using nio ?

NIO won't help *per se*.  It certainly won't prevent the low-bandwidth responses tying up threads for long periods of time.

I think what you would need to do is to implement downloads in a special web container.  I'm not sure, but I think that Servlet 3.0 with async mode might do the trick.