# Limit Speed Download in Java

Tags: java

i dont want use the Sleep method to limit speed upload download in my program. My teacher say there was another way to do this, please help me! Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code first of all ? Everything else comes second.  Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you are using servlets, here: [Restrict download file bandwidth/speed in Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060414) you will find a complete solution. Otherwise you can easily customize it.

Comment: i use the InputStream() to do that (copy file, or download from internet), how can i do? :D