# How to run a method after sending a servlet response while also accepting further requests?

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

The scenario I am trying to complete is the following:

1. The client submits a HTTP POST request to the servlet.
2. The servlet sends a response to the client confirming the request has been received.
3. The servlet then sends an email notification to the system administrator.

So far I am able to complete the following steps in the order described above, however I run into an issue at the end. If the client makes another HTTP request to the same or another servlet while the email notification method `EmailUtility.sendNotificationEmail()` is still running, the servlet will not run any further code until this email method is completed (I am using `javax.mail` to send emails if that matters).

I have tried to use `AsyncContext` to get around this (which I may be using incorrectly), but unfortunately the issue still remains.

How can I make the `EmailUtility.sendNotificationEmail()` run in a different thread/asynchronously so that the servlets do not have to wait for this method to complete?

This is my code so far:

```
//Step 1: Client submits POST request to servlet.
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    request.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);

    //Step 2: Servlet sends response to client.
    response.getWriter().write("Your request has been received");
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();

    //Step 3: Servlet send email notification.
    final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
    acontext.start(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EmailUtility.sendNotificationEmail();
            acontext.complete();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Send the email before replying to the request. it is generally asynchronous, so the reply would be received beforehand...

Comment: I have tried sending the email beforehand but unfortunately the response is not sent until the email method is completed, so the issue still remains.

Comment: I don't think `AsyncContext` can be used after sending the response; it's meant for asynchronous preparation of a response.

Comment: Yeah I think I have been using this incorrectly, as the following post explains "There is no thread created by startAsync! It just tells the servlet container: hey, although the doGet/doPost method finished, I am not done with this request, please do not close." https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066273/7155133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the issue by using `ExecutorService` as follows:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        EmailUtility.sendNotificationEmail();
    }
});

executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: can we able to pass parameters httprequest & httpresponse to sendNotificationEmail method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple, like a thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       EmailUtility.sendNotificationEmail();
   }
}, "Send E-mail").start();
```

Comment: From my understanding, using threads in a servlet environment is not recommended. Thanks for the help though.